# Как в fetch получить один столбец из курсора, для которого нельзя указать %rowtype?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Пишу процедуру, в которой получаю курсор из другой процедуры.

Нужно с помощью `fetch` получить первый столбец из курсора. Так как там много столбцов, то не желательно бы заводить переменную под каждую, чтобы не было такого:

```
fetch into v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8
```

А так:

```
row_set  v_cursor%rowtype;
```

не получается сделать, потому что объявление курсора находится в другой процедуре.

`bulk collect` я не пробовал, но в курсоре возвращаются разные типы, а он, как я понимаю, может вернуть только в массив.

Comment: _Тоже не получается сделать, потому что объявление курсора находится в другой процедуре_, а зачем вы тогда его туда поместили?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автор вопроса [прокомментировал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1191094/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-fetch-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%86-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-rowty#comment2078949_1191153):

> А как сделать, чтобы эта процедура именно возвращала курсор?

Oбъявленный в PL/SQL явный курсор нельзя вeрнуть из процедуры или функции. Вернуть можно только курсор с типом `REF CURSOR`. Эти типы несовместимы, т.е. нельзя переменную явного курсора присвоить переменной курсора. Но можно обрабатывать явный курсор в табличной функции, а её результат возвращать как курсор.

Посмотрите, как это сделать:

```
create or replace package pack2 as
    cursor cur1 is
        select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
        select 4 col1, 5 col2, 6 col3 from dual;
    type currows is table of cur1%rowtype;
    type refcursor is ref cursor return cur1%rowtype;
    procedure process;
    procedure opencur (rc out refcursor);  
    function getdata return currows pipelined;  
end;
/
create or replace package body pack2 as
    function getdata return currows pipelined is
    begin
        for r in cur1 loop pipe row (r); 
        end loop;
        return;
    end;
    procedure opencur (rc out refcursor) is 
    begin
        open rc for select * from table (getdata ());
    end;
    procedure process is
        rc refcursor;
        rs currows; 
    begin 
        opencur (rc);
        fetch rc bulk collect into rs;
        for i in 1..rs.count loop
            dbms_output.put_line ('col2['||i||']='||rs(i).col2); 
        end loop;
    end;
end;
/
```

Такое решение будет работать внутри блока и с ним можно вернуть откртый курсор:

```
exec pack2.process;

col2[1]=2
col2[2]=5

var rc refcursor
exec pack2.opencur (:rc);

      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         4          5          6
```

Comment: Это то, что нужно, спасибо большое за табличные функции, я про них не знал)

Comment: Рад был помочь! Если найдётся немного свободного времени, посмотрите [самоответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1192981) по схожей теме. Мне важен feedback, понятно ли я там всё изложил.

Comment: там всё понятно, ещё раз большое спасибо)

Answer (score 4):

Создайте пакет и поместите объявление курсора в тело пакета.

Это будет выглядеть примерно как в воиспроизводимом примере ниже:

```
create or replace package pack1 as
    procedure process;
end;
/
create or replace package body pack1 as
    cursor cur1 is
        select 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3 from dual union all
        select 4 col1, 5 col2, 6 col3 from dual;
    type currows is table of cur1%rowtype;
    procedure openCursor is
    begin 
        open cur1;
    end; 
    function fetchCursor return currows is
        ret currows; 
    begin 
        fetch cur1 bulk collect into ret;
        close cur1;
        return ret;
    end;
    procedure process is
        rs currows;
    begin 
        openCursor;
        rs := fetchCursor ();
        for i in 1..rs.count loop
            dbms_output.put_line ('col2['||i||']='||rs(i).col2); 
        end loop;
    end;
end;
/
```

Запуск и результат:

```
exec pack1.process;

col2[1]=2
col2[2]=5
```

Comment: Но процедура перестала возвращать курсор, она с ним работает сама. А как сделать, чтобы это процедура именно возвращала курсор? Просто курсор из этой процедуры уже дальше читает джава

Comment: Курсор нельзя вeрнуть из процедуры или функции. Можно только вернуть ссылку на курсор (ref cursor). Оба эти типа несовместимы, т.е нельзя просто дать ссылку на явный курсор. Думаю, лучше задать новый вопрос и указаать в нём  больше подробностей, или, что самое простое, сделать минимальный воспроизводимый пример.