# В чем разница между явным курсором и переменной курсора с типом REF CURSOR?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-cursor

Допустим, определены такие два курсора, явный `ec` и курсор переменная `rc`:

```
declare
    cursor ec is select 'name1' name from dual;
    type refcursor is ref cursor;
    rc refcursor;
begin 
    open ec;
    rc := ec;
end;
/
ORA-06550: line 7, column 11:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Компилятор считает, что присваивание одного к другому это неверное выражение.

Но ведь, как известно, оба эти типа курсора являются указателями на контекстную область выполнения DML запроса.

Так какая всё таки между ними разница? И как с ними работать?

Comment: схожий вопрос:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1191094. Идея этого самоответа, помочь понять разницу между различными типами курсоров, с пониманием которой у автора схожего вопроса возникли некоторые трудности.

Answer (score 3):

Как сказано в [документации в гл. 6.4 Cursor Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-4A6E054A-4002-418D-A1CA-DE849CD7E6D5%5D):

> Note: Cursor variables and explicit cursors are not interchangeable — you cannot use one where the other is expected.

Эти типы несовместимы. Нельзя переменную явного курсора (*explicit cursor*), объявленную с ключевым словом `CURSOR`, присвоить курсор переменной с типом `REF CURSOR` (*cursor variable*).

Явный курсор это особый тип переменной, который создавался только для PL/SQL и может быть использован только в PL/SQL контексте.

Oба типа курсора являются указателями (*pointer*). Но область памяти, куда указывает явный курсор, [цитирую из документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-89E0242F-42AC-4B21-9DF1-ACD6F4FC03B9):

> A cursor is a pointer to a **private SQL area** that stores information about processing a specific SELECT or DML statement.

То есть, там, где хранятся все PL/SQL переменные сессии. Поэтому у этого типа переменной есть ещё одно имя - курсор сессии. А область памяти, куда [указывает переменная курсора](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-4A6E054A-4002-418D-A1CA-DE849CD7E6D5%5D):

> Before you can reference a cursor variable, you must make it point to a **SQL work area**

Другими словами, причина несовместимости этих переменных - их различная "природа".

Для лучшего понимания, можно так определить основное их отличие:

- переменная явного курсора указывает *только на один определённый* SQL запрос, его нельзя изменить
- переменная курсора может принять указатель на *любой* SQL запрос, ей можно присвоить указатель на новый запрос

Хотя явный курсор это тоже переменная, но её значение нельзя ни изменить, ни присвоить. Даже переменной другого явного курсора с абсолютно идентичным запросом:

```
declare
    cursor ec is select 'name1' name from dual;
    cursor oc return ec%rowtype;
    cursor oc is select 'name1' name from dual;
begin 
    open ec;
    oc := ec;
end;
/
ORA-06550: line 7, column 5:
PLS-00321: expression 'OC' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement
```

Поэтому, единственный способ преобразовать явный курсор в переменную курсора, это - открыть новый курсор, где в запросе в качестве таблицы использовать результат выполнения явного курсора. Один конкретный и очень гибкий пример есть [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1192895). Ещё один самый минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
create or replace package pack as
    cursor cur is
        select 1 id, 'name1' name from dual union all
        select 2 id, 'name2' name from dual;
    type currows is table of cur%rowtype;
    type refcursor is ref cursor;
    procedure proc (rc out refcursor); 
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as
    procedure proc (rc out refcursor) is 
        rs currows;
    begin 
        open cur;
        fetch cur bulk collect into rs;
        close cur;
        open rc for select * from table (rs); 
    end;
end;
/
var rc refcursor 
exec pack.proc (:rc)

    ATTR_1 ATTR_
---------- -----
         1 name1
         2 name2
```